# Reversing list in for loop

Tags: python, list

I want to create a string with values from the list. I am using following code and it’s working fine.

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,4]
st = ''.join(str(d) for d in ls[::-1])
```

But, when I am using it in the following way, it's performing better.

```
st = ''.join(str(d) for d in ls)[::-1]
```

I know that re[::-1] do a shallow copy to reverse it but why the second one is better?

Comment: Don't call your list `re`.

Comment: I dont see the difference between the 2. The second one is same as the first line of code.

Comment: Okay fair point. There is a very, very common package in the standard library called `re`, for regular expression parsing. You should avoid using that name for anything else because doing so will override any `import re` at the top of your module.

Comment: There's a big difference between actively shadowing a built-in name (like `list`) and using the name of a module you haven't imported (`re`, in this case).

Comment: I wouldn't use the slice at all. Use `reversed(re)`, which presumably iterates over the list directly without making a shallow copy first.

Comment: @chepner I take the point to some extent (e.g. you see people use `string` as a variable name, and fair enough when the `string` module is of reduced importance these days), but it just struck me that with a package as commonly used as `re`, it is one worth getting in the habit of avoiding using for anything else.

Comment: I have updated my question. I don’t want to reverse my list so I am not using reversed()

Comment: @mary_jane I am curious if you find out the actual reason? 
Also is it really the case or just some misunderstanding from your end?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `reversed()`:

> function returns an iterator that accesses the given sequence in the
> reverse order.

PS. taking in account that you should not be using `re` as list name to avoid any conflicts with the `re` package:

```
x_lst = [1,2,3,4,4]
print(''.join(str(e) for e in reversed(x_lst)))
```

Comment: Feels like it should be at most a comment. This doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: I have updated the question and I don’t want to use reversed(). I just wanted to know the difference between those two lines.